# How to transform a nested for-loop operation to a more efficient code in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am a dilettante when it comes to R coding. I am trying to run the following code for one of the tasks. My basic purpose is to count the number of attractions within the proximity of 2kms of a specific location, both attractions, and the locations are specified by respective longitude and latitude. The number of records in the main data set is around 29K and while the number of attractions is 28. How can I convert the following code in a better performing R code instead (the current one is really crude and not at all a good practice)

```
for(i in 1:nrow(mainData)) {
  attr_count[i] = 0  
  loc_coord = c(mainData$longitude[i],mainData$latitude[i])
  for(j in 1:nrow(ny_attractions)) {
    attr_coord = c(ny_attractions$lon[j],ny_attractions$lat[j])
    dist = distVincentySphere(attr_coord,loc_coord)
    if(dist <= 2000) {
      attr_count[i] = attr_count[i] + 1
    } 
  }
}
```

[EDIT]: My apologies for not putting it clearly earlier. Here's an example of what I am trying to achieve. I have 2 data sets -

Dataset - 1 (NYC_attractions) (27 records)

[image]

Dataset-2 (master data for house listings) (29K records)

[image]

Now, I need to add one more column (num_of_attractions) in Dataset-2, representing the number of attractions within 2Kms of the specified listing (i.e. per record in data set-2)

Hope, this explains the problem

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you are trying to manipulate spatial data. There are a lot of resources to do what you want to do in packages `sp`, `rgeos` or `sf`. Please give us a reproducible example.

Comment: Please post sample data to work with. Also post what the expected outcome should look like

Answer (score 1):

Hello your question is partly answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49860968/3042154. As you use geodetic coordinates (lat/lon) instead of projected coordinates (meters) it can be done in to steps. First roughly select potential neighbours using euclidian distance using given answer then refine the selection by using your distance

Comment: Awesome!! Not partially, this answers my question completely. However, I need to still figure out whether it works with longitude and latitude instead of points. Thank you so much for your help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Nice to hear it! If you consider your question answered please mark it so or upvote my answer :-)